# Merge using two columns and at the same time make a melt

Tags: r

```
dfa <- data.frame(numid = c(1,2), numt = c(3,5), date = c("2012-03-21 12:32:11", "2011-11-03 04:32:11"), session = c("sessionA", "sessionB"))
dfb <- data.frame(numid = c(1,1,2), nums = c(402,321,34), date = c("2012-03-21 12:52:11","2012-03-21 12:41:32","2011-11-04 04:32:11"), session = c("sessionA", "sessionA", "sessionB"))
```

I would like to merge both data frame using the columns numid and session.
However the fine data frame I would like to have the format as a melt option of the dfb where the numid is the same as of dfa and have the same value also in session column add the date of dfa.
Example output:

```
dff <- data.frame(numid = c(1,1,2), date_dfa = c("2012-03-21 12:32:11", "2012-03-21 12:32:11", "2011-11-03 04:32:11"), nums = c(402,321,34), date = c("2012-03-21 12:52:11","2012-03-21 12:41:32","2011-11-04 04:32:11"), session = c("sessionA", "sessionA", "sessionB"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
#Merge
Merged <- merge(dfa,dfb,by=c('numid','session'),suffixes = c('dfa','dfb'))

  numid  session numt             datedfa nums             datedfb
1     1 sessionA    3 2012-03-21 12:32:11  402 2012-03-21 12:52:11
2     1 sessionA    3 2012-03-21 12:32:11  321 2012-03-21 12:41:32
3     2 sessionB    5 2011-11-03 04:32:11   34 2011-11-04 04:32:11
```